# Does running a command using sudo cause future commands in the same session to also be run as root?

Tags: linux, sudo, make

I was in a hurry trying to get a project up and building, using raw make.
I had a Makefile whose relevant bits went like this:

```
TARGET := libtest

BIN_DIR := bin
BUILD_DIR := build

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    -@rm -rvf $(BIN_DIR)/*
    -@rm -rvf $(BUILD_DIR)/*
```

I removed the `BIN_DIR` variable in favour of defining the full export path in `TARGET`, which resulted in `-@rm -rvf $(BIN_DIR)/*` resolving to `rm -rvf /*` - after I next ran `make`, I have no `/bin` folder, among other things despite CTRL+C'ing almost immediately. Fun!

I think I can resolve the problem, but how did this even happen? I think I ran `sudo` maybe 5-10 minutes before in the same terminal I ran `make` in, in order to install a package, but I was under the impression nothing is run as root unless you specifically `sudo` it.

Comment: When you used `sudo` earlier, did you do that to get an interactive root shell, and did you not exit that shell before running `make`?

Comment: No, running a command with `sudo` doesn't cause future commands to run under root account. Have you run `sudo make`? Maybe you worked as root all the time, check with `id`. Or maybe you have broken permissions for `/`, show output of `ls -dl /`.

Comment: I didn't run `su` at any point so I dont see why I should have been in a root shell (`id` confirms this), and I didn't run `sudo make`.

`ls -dl /` gives `drwxrwxrwx 17 root root 4096 Apr  4 12:20 /`. so I don't think theres anything up there, but maybe the permissions were broken for `/bin` - I can't see many other files that shouldn't have user permissions that have been deleted;

Comment: You have `w` for the world. Does `touch /TEST-FILE` work?

Comment: Yes it does, that would be the problem. No clue how thats happened, I don't think I've ever changed the permissions of `/`, let alone adding `w` for other.

Comment: "ls -dl / gives drwxrwxrwx 17 root root 4096 Apr 4 12:20 /. so I don't think theres anything up there." -- look again.